# React.js - componentWillReceiveProps being hit twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React.js component that's being rendered like so:

```
    <Social email={this.state.email} />;
```

There are some events on the page that update `this.state.email`, and as a result, go through render, which sends a new `email` prop to the `Social` component.

In this `Social` component, I'm listening for updates like so:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    console.log('received props update', nextProps.email);
    this.doSomeWork();
  }
```

That console line is being rendered twice which makes the UI flash twice along with calls to social networks.

I could always do something like:

```
    if (nextProps.email != this.props.email) {
      this.doSomeWork();
    }
```

But it felt a little hacky...

Is the double message expected? and if so, curious why?

If not, what's the best way to both track down and eliminate it?

Comment: Double render === double calls, rethink your rendering. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `Social` component is probably being rendered twice because `setState` is called twice on the parent component. It may be setting properties other than `email` but your render function is called so the `Social` component renders twice.

You can implement `shouldComponentUpdate` method in the `Social` component to prevent second rendering:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.email != this.props.email;
}
```

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` feels like a band-aid, right?

Comment: In the `componentWillReceiveProps`, I printed `this.props` and `nextProps` and only the first time are they different. They second render, they are the same. Should `componentWillReceiveProps` run on state change as well?

Comment: No, you should use `componentWillUpdate` to perform operations in response to a state change. You can see the documentation here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Ok, so why might I be seeing an update come through `componentWillReceiveProps` where `nextProps.email` and `this.props.email` is the same?

Comment: React does not know if the object you send as props is immutable (it can be a complex object and you can mutate it in place in the parent component) therefore it can not a make a reference comparison for you. Rather it allows you to decide to render or not through `shouldComponentUpdate` function. In this function you can use reference based comparison if you have immutable objects. Or come up with other logic for mutable objects.

Comment: I toyed around with why multiple updates would be coming for awhile, but couldn't get to the bottom of it. I sensed that it was internal to state change as well, but it doesn't match up with the documentation. Do you view `shouldComponentUpdate` as a band-aid? It sounds like you're suggesting there's no problem using it.

Comment: Using `shouldComponentUpdate` is totally advisable as your render comparison becomes constant time. This is why frameworks like OM (https://github.com/swannodette/om) is very fast. If you can guarantee immutability and just compare references in the `shouldComponentUpdate` function then you will even skip virtual dom diff. May be reading about immutability helpers may help: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html