# react render method is called Twice, changing url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am newbie in react. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628504/react-js-componentwillreceiveprops-being-hit-twice) , but didn't solve my problem. I think I'm wrong with componentWillReceiveProps comprehension . My component and it's parent are like this:
the parent:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router';

export default class App extends React.Component {

items = [
    {id: 1086, title: 'MENU1'},
    {id: 1083, title: 'MENU2'},
    {id: 1093, title: 'MENU3'}]

renderItems = ()=> {
    return this.items.map((item, index)=> {
        let url = 'content/' + item.id;
        return (<li key={index}><Link to={url} activeClassName="active">{item.title}</Link></li>);
    });
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 style={{textAlign:'center'}}>My First React App</h1>
            <ul className="nav nav-pills nav-justified">{this.renderItems()}</ul>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

the child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UmContent from './UmContent'
import $ from 'jquery';
import ProgressBar from 'progressbar.js';


export default class UmContentContainer extends Component {
state = {
    data: ''
}

firstInitial = true;

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.firstInitial) {
        let props = this.props;
        this.sendRequestToServer(props);
        this.firstInitial = false;
    }
}

sendRequestToServer = (props)=> {
    if (!props || !props.params || !props.params.id) {
        return;
    }
    let itemId = props.params.id;
    let that = this;
    this.setState({data: itemId});
     }

componentWillReceiveProps(props, states) {
    this.sendRequestToServer(props);
     console.log(props.params.id);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="col-md-12">
            <h1>{this.state.data}</h1>
        </div>);
}
```

}

and index.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link,hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import App from './App';
import UmContentContainer from './Umbreco/UmContentContainer';

render((
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="/content/:id" component={UmContentContainer} />
    </Route>
</Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

after first mounting , console writes "id" twice. I can't understand why?

Comment: Have you checked how the `props` differ from each other on the two renders?

Comment: @Scarysize in both of them , value of id in props are the same.

Comment: @sahar How about other props? Have you tried just `console.log(props)`.

Comment: @Waiski if you mean "this.props" , for first time that componentWillReceiveProps is called , the id in this.props.params doesn't update and has previous value . but for second time it will be updated

Comment: @sahar So are you saying that the `id` does have different values for the two runs of `componentWillReceiveProps`? Or what do you mean by "for second time it will be updated"?

Comment: @sahar Also, could you show how you render the `UmContentContainer`? Your `App` component does not seem to include it at all.

Comment: @Waiski for your firat question: yes id has different value in `this.props` that is logical because in first render it won't be update in componentWillReceiveProps. I think I should mention that `this.props` is different from `props`(in componentWillReceiveProps(props)).and for second question , I should say update my code .

Comment: it should not be called twice! are you using any redux or flux?

Comment: @vijayst . no , it's weird for me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136836/react-component-render-is-called-multiple-times-when-pushing-new-url) , I was wrong , actually it was about the hashHistory and pushing new url . not `componentWillReceiveProps`.