# ComponentWillReceiveProps called twice with react and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a problem with ComponentWillReceiveProps cycle, because its called twice, I don't know why but I suppose thats happen because Connect react-redux and react-router are implemented. How can I stop this "issue"?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(this.props.match.url !== nextProps.match.url){
        console.log('its diferent')
    }else{
        console.log('its same url')
    }
}
```

**output**:

```
// its same url
// its same url
```

Thanks for your attention. PD: this is not a possible duplicate from [react+redux][2] because that thread doesn't have a correct answer.

[image: Redux]

Comment: Need to see the surrounding code. i.e. the parent component to this one

Comment: Parent Component of PostContainer? are Middleware.jsx (handle routes)  
`<switch>
 <Route ..>
 <Route ..>
<switch>`
(see update)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js - componentWillReceiveProps being hit twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628504/react-js-componentwillreceiveprops-being-hit-twice)

Comment: You can use [why did you update](https://github.com/maicki/why-did-you-update) to help you track this. Probably a problem is in parent component.

Comment: Middleware component? thanks for your answer.So.. connect and react-redux aren't an issue? thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: what do you think? [link](https://imgur.com/a/FEEG8)

Comment: Oops... i'm idiot. I call static method inside my component (PostContainer) 
`static requestInitialData() ...
...if(!this.props.data){
 dispatch(PostContainer.requestInitialData(url)); 
}`
Thats render twice same component. Works great when change post url,
dont call twice or more times my async functions to fetch data,but console.log still
says 
`// changed url!
// same url
// same url`
Thanks for your help. @MotiKorets